# Can't access directory using path

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, python-os

I have set up tensorflow GPU docker from https://tensorflow.org/install/docker. I am trying to load directory using `import os` library in Jupyter notebook on top of tensorflow GPU in Ubuntu. I can access `import os` library and fetch directory details using standalone python in terminal but can't able to fetch directory details in Jupyter notebook on top of tensorflow gpu.

**Standalone Python:**

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> base_dir="/home/chief/Desktop/ML/data"
>>> print(len(os.listdir(base_dir)))
3
```

**Jupyter notebook using tensorflow gpu:**
[image]

I am running the tensorflow gpu using the following command:

```
sudo docker run --runtime=nvidia -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3
```

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: look for cwd = os.getcwd() check if you're on correct path.

Comment: It gives current directory as `/notebooks`

Comment: you have to walk thru the files and directories using Python os module then you'll see may be try mounting local folder to docker. well I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can able to solve this using following command:

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia -it -p 8888:8888 -v /home/chief/Desktop/ML/:/notebooks tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the tailing '/'

> base_dir="/home/chief/Desktop/ML/data/"

Comment: I would refer you to this link. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm 
Check if you have files or directories inside data folder.

Comment: I can access using python shell but can't able to access it using Jupyter notebook in tensorflow gpu environment.

Comment: import pathlib 

# define the path currentDirectory = pathlib.Path('.') for currentFile in currentDirectory.iterdir(): print(currentFile)
Whyn't you are using pathlib

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo docker run --runtime=nvidia -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3 -v /home/chief/Desktop/ML/data:/notebooks/ML_data
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Should I run this along with `sudo docker run --runtime=nvidia -it -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3` ? Or need to run in two different terminal?

Comment: I am getting this error: `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"-v\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
`